# Apache Airflow - Any have a scrip with tables of metadata?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-webserver

have a problema when i need create all tables of metadata on airflow.

I created a docker-compose that points to on premise mariadb-mysql and when i up the compose, some tables don't create all variable or directly do not create the tables

This is the problen when i try to execute airflow.

[image]

Create many tables manually but difficult to do with all.

Any have a script.sql with tables for mariadb-mysql??

At this moment y use apache airflow 2.1.3 and python 3.9

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].